# Pass Structure Data To Dbus

Tags: linux, shell, dbus

I have a process running that has a DBUS endpoint which takes a structure. This was developed using qt and q-dbus.

In dfeet I see the endpoint method details as such

```
setScreen (Struct of (Int32, Struct of (String), Boolean, Struct of (Int32, UInt32, Byte, Boolean, Byte, Int32, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String), Struct of (Int32, UInt32, Byte, Boolean, Byte, Int32, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String)) screenUi) ↦ (Boolean arg_0)
```

I am trying to figure out how to send some sample data in this format. Any pointers?

[image]

I tried using dbus-send using the below but got a format error

```
    gdbus call --session --dest com.semanect.S8Displayd  --object-path /com/semanect/S8Displayd --method com.semanect.S8Displayd.SetScreen "(0,('JBN1'),true,(2,0,0,true,0,0,'','','','','abc','def','ghi','mmm'),(2,0,0,true,0,0,'','','','','abc','def','ghi','mmm')"
Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such method 'SetScreen' in interface 'com.semaconnect.S8Displayd' at object path '/com/semaconnect/S8Displayd' (signature 's')
```

Using d-feet introspect I get the method dbus format as

```
 '    <method name="setScreen">\n'
 '      <arg type="b" direction="out"/>\n'
 '      <arg name="screenUi" type="(i(s)b(iuybyisssssssss)(iuybyisssssssss))" '
 'direction="in"/>\n'
 '      <annotation name="org.qtproject.QtDBus.QtTypeName.In0" '
 'value="screen_ui_t"/>\n'
 '    </method>\n'
```

I am open to using python also if anyone has suggestions / pointers on how to use that

Update :

I was able to send data using dbus-send

```
gdbus call --session --dest com.semanect.S8Displayd  --object-path /com/semanect/S8Displayd --method com.semanect.S8Displayd.setScreen "(0,('JBN1',),true,(2,0,0,true,0,0,'','','','','abc','def','ghi','mmm','kkk'),(2,0,0,true,0,0,'','','','','abc','def','ghi','mmm','kkk'))"
(true,)
```

How can I do this using a python script / C program ?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @BarmarI am not expecting it to be, neither am i asking for someone to write a program for me. I am simply asking for syntax help from people who know dbus. Added what I have tried using dbus-send

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but more a call for more information but because of formatting challenges it is easier to post it here...

I personally find the method signature from `busctl` a little easier to read. Could you post in your question the output from the following command:

```
busctl introspect com.semanect.S8Displayd  /com/semanect/S8Displayd
```

As you mentioned Python. I find [pydbus](https://pypi.org/project/pydbus/) very good for D-Bus. Could you post the output from the following also:

```py
import pydbus
adapter = pydbus.SessionBus().get('com.semanect.S8Displayd', '/com/semanect/S8Displayd')
help(adapter.SetScreen)
```

Comment: Help on method setScreen in module pydbus.proxy_method:

setScreen(screenUi:(i(s)b(iuybyisssssssss)(iuybyisssssssss))) -> b method of DBUS.<CompositeObject> instance

Comment: thanks !@ukBaz. looking at the introspect output gave me a clue on how the input might be formatted. able to communicate using dbus-send now